# Raspberry Pi create user with one file permission

Tags: linux, permissions, raspberry-pi, sudo

I know how to create a new user on the Pi with all the same privileges as pi from this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7133/how-to-change-pi-sudo-permissions

But how do you create a user with just one file permission? I mean that I want to create a user Alice that can only edit / rm / scp /  the file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf. I don't want them to be able to read or modify any other files on the Pi. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poked around a bit--mostly on other SO questions--and found this program called Jailkit, which seems to be designed to do exactly what you want.

http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/

If that doesn't help, these two answers might have hints for you. They're not duplicate questions, but they each hold a chunk of what you might need.

To strip permissions: [How to restrict a linux user to be only able to read /home/user and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527876/how-to-restrict-a-linux-user-to-be-only-able-to-read-home-user-and-nothing-else)

To give permission to that one file: https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation

Comment: These look good, but I'm wondering if I'm doing too much to solve a small problem. I've realized there's only one directory on the Pi that I **don't** want this new user to read/modify/write. Can I achieve closing it off to the user just by using chmod commands? It's a whole directory, not just one file.

Comment: Probably you want to solve that using groups. Here's some documentation for you. https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups#working-with-groups

Comment: The last link in my answer also has some relevant info.